# Android Layout switching id's at runtime

Tags: android, exception, layout, user-interface, view

In my project I'm using the Card Library and something really strange just happened to me...

i have a custom card that uses a custom layout with a CardThumbnailView and a TextView,

this is the layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
              android:gravity="fill_vertical"
              android:layout_height="96dp">

    <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.component.CardThumbnailView
                style="@style/card_thumbnail_outer_layout"
                android:id="@+id/card_exrc_thumb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_exrc_title"
            style="@style/exrc_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

as you can see the thumbnail view has the id of "card_exrc_thumb" and the text view has the id of "card_exrc_title".

and this is how i use them in my card class:

```
protected TextView mExrcTitle;
protected CardThumbnailView mThumb;

public void setupInnerViewElements(ViewGroup parent, View view) {

        // Retrieve elements

        mThumb = (CardThumbnailView) parent.findViewById(R.id.card_exrc_thumb);
        mExrcTitle = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.card_exrc_title);

        // Set Thumb
        CardThumbnail cardThumbail = new CardThumbnail(cContext);
        cardThumbail.setDrawableResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mThumb.addCardThumbnail(cardThumbail);

        // Set Title
        mExrcTitle.setText(exCurrent.sName);
    }
```

The exception im getting is an illeagal cast exception - like im trying to cast a textview into a cardthumbnailview and vice versa...

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.component.CardThumbnailView
01-02 23:19:26.281: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at gym.ExerciseCard.setupInnerViewElements(ExerciseCard.java:48)
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the code for you custom element?

Comment: Is it possible that the XML above is not the XML that has actually been inflated?  Maybe 'card_exrc_thumb' exists in another view as a TextView?  Do a file search and verify.  Also, try removing the cast and just set the type to 'View', and see if the View is the one you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Project... Clean ... All projects. If that doesn't work delete the /bin and /gen directories manually and restart Eclipse.

Comment: This looks like a runtime exception, not an eclipse issue.

Comment: @NathanielWaggoner I'm not sure if this will fix the problem in this particular instance so, personally, I would have made it a comment. However, sometimes `ClassCastException`s can occur at runtime due to Eclipse not recognizing a change in xml. So a clean and rebuild can help if that is the case.

Comment: I've not run into that issue before, but I'll buy it.  Eclipse is a huge ol' mess.

Comment: I've definitely seen this exact problem be fixed from the steps in my answer, and I'm 80% sure this particular instance will be fixed by my answer, so I feel it is better as an answer.